# Snake with Python and Pygame

Tags: python

I'm currently doing a snake project for my coding class. I was able to get the snake to move, with each body part following the one in front of it. However, I am having difficulty in trying to change the snake's direction. Here is a current sample code.

```
snakeHeadX = 400
snakeHeadY = 400

a = [[snakeHeadX,snakeHeadY],[snakeHeadX - 20,snakeHeadY], [snakeHeadX-20-20,snakeHeadY]]

for i in range(len(a) -1, -1, -1):
    if i == 0:
        continue

    [a[i][0], a[i][1]] = [a[i-1][0], a[i-1][1]]
    if i == 0:
        continue
a[0][0] = a[0][0] + 20
```

The `a[0][0] = a[0][0] + 20` is what moves the snake head location plus 20 on the X. Any ideas on how I would be able to change the direction, for example saying `a[0][1] = a[0][1] + 20`, which would move the snake's head up 20 on the Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create variable 'direction' that can store value in which direction your head is going (i.e. "up", "down", "left" or "right") and based on that you can move your snake
But then every "block" of your snake will change direction at the same time.

Here's what you need to do:

```py
    snake_start_x = 400
    snake_start_y = 400
    snake_block_size = 20

    snake = [] #please, use names that make sense, not a
    for i in range(3): #a bit more elegant than what you did to create snake
        snake.append([snake_start_x-i*snake_block_size, snake_start_y])

    def move_head(direction):
        global snake #if you would pass snake as an argument it would create another instance. Here where're working directly on snake

        if direction == "up": #change y by -20
            snake[0][1] -= snake_block_size

        elif direction == "down": #change y by 20
            snake[0][1] += snake_block_size

        elif direction == "left": #change x by -20
            snake[0][0] -= snake_block_size

        elif direction == "right": #change x by 20
            snake[0][0] += snake_block_size

    def move_tail(): #
        global snake
        for i in range(len(snake)-1, 0, -1): #looping backwards without including head
            snake[i][0] = snake[i-1][0]
            snake[i][1] = snake[i-1][1]
```

Then you need to call it in your loop

```py
    d = "up" # you can change it on key-press for example
    while True: #your main loop
        move_tail() #first snake moves tail up to it's head
        move_head(d) #then head "bounces" in the right direction

        #draw it then or whatever...
```

I think there are batter ways to do this(maybe make snake an object?) but I came up with this one that is relatively simple.

EDIT: you can add collision detection in move_head function or after move is done call another function that checks that. Here's an example:

```py
    def is_in_wall(WIDTH, HEIGHT):
        global snake
        if snake[0][0] < 0: # too far left
            return True
        elif snake[0][0]+snake_block_size > WIDTH: # too far right
            return True
        elif snake[0][1] < 0: # too far up
            return True
        elif snake[0][1]+snake_block_size > HEIGHT: # too far down
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

and in your loop:

```py
    if is_in_wall(WIDTH, HEIGHT): #WIDTH and HEIGHT are dimensions of your window 
        #die or stop the game bacause snake has crossed the border
```

Comment: How would I make snake an object? Could you give a code example?